# how to make 'ack' command print the filename that has found the result on every line

Tags: search, grep, ack

By default [`ack`](http://betterthangrep.com/documentation/) command prints the output in follwing way

```
ack --jsp '</div>'

a.jsp
5:</span></div>
10:</table></div>
b.jsp
3:</div><div>xyz
8:</div><a>
```

is there any way to output the result in following way ?

```
<filename>:<linenum>:<matchedtext>   

a.jsp:5:</div>
a.jsp:10:</div>
b.jsp:3:</div>
b.jsp:8:</div>
```

Though there is `--output=expr` to output match based on regex capture group I am not sure if there is any way to get the name of the file that has matched text along with the line number

```
ack --jsp -o -h --output=':$1:$2' '(</(div)>)'

:</div>:div
:</div>:div
:</div>:div
:</div>:div
```

if not possible with ack, is there any alternate way to do it ?

Answer (score 2):

Ok a quick scan through ack source I found following command line option to get required result

```
ack --jsp --nogroup -o '(</(div)>)'


a.jsp:5:</div>
a.jsp:10:</div>
b.jsp:3:</div>
b.jsp:8:</div>
```

or

```
ack --jsp --nogroup --output='$2' '(</(div)>)'


a.jsp:5:div
a.jsp:10:div
b.jsp:3:div
b.jsp:8:div
```